# paypal ipn not getting verified

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using the following code for paypal ipn:

```
    <?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("PayPal") or die(mysql_error());

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

// PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!

}

else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

// PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY!

}
}
fclose ($fp);
}

    ?>
```

After testing in every which way, I am getting everything to work except when:

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
```

does not work

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 1)
```

WORKS

Obviously its not getting verified as I'm sending IPN from sandbox.

What could be missing?

Comment: If you're in sandbox mode, then use `ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com` instead of `ssl://www.paypal.com` in the hostname parameter for `fsockopen`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you both say that `strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 1` is true, $res is 1 character "bigger" than the string VERIFIED. My guess is that $res has a \n character at the end or something else that needs to be stripped. Try doing something like `str_replace('\n', '', $res)` before calling the lines with strcmp. Just thinking out loud though. If this is not working, let me know.

Fyi, PayPal has sample code online to verify an IPN in PHP using cURL. 
Link: http://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples#instantpaymentnotification